# DR Design for MobileFirst 8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, disaster-recovery

Is there any document on how to setup the DR env for MFP 8?

May I know if the following configuration for the DR solution is ok:

- The DR site is a cold standby
- Production and DR site are installed separately (IHS/WAS/DB2), and the data in DB2 will be synchronized through hardware sync (eg. SAN disk)
- And there is only one adapter(with the same content) installed in both DR and Production
- The DR site has a different set of ip addresses from production addresses

When there is any disaster, we simply route the traffic to DR site and allow DR DB2 instance mount the SAN disk and serve the request.

- Product Version: 8.0
- Deployment Environment: On Premises
- Application Type: Web

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The DR solution that you described works fine. I am not sure about how DB2 hardware synchronization (SANdisk) works, but I have seen customers using DB2 Q-replication for the same purpose. Usually customers only replicate the Runtime tables. That means the Admin and Config tables are not replicated normally. This is because the updates to apps and adapters deployed on MFP is less frequent activities. In this case, if you are deploying an updated adapter in production, you need to deploy the same updated adapter on DR too. But if the DB2 hardware synchronization is replicating all the tables (Admin, Config, Runtime and Push), then you don't need to redeploy updates to apps and adapter to DR.

There is no DR setup document for 8.0, but there are some blogs on Q-replication : https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2018/08/05/Db2-Qreplication-Mobile-Foundation/

There are some DR setup doc for 7.1, that can be used for reference : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1501_tissandier/1501_tissandier.html

Comment: Thanks for your information, to summarize the proposed MobileFirst DR solution description and your response, I have drafted 2 slides to make it more clear. Can you kindly check if the MobileFirst DR solution described in the slides can be supported in MPF v8? The key point here is that the DR machines in customer's DR site are having different IP addresses and hostnames from the production machines. Also whole MFP Database contents are replicated from production to DR site via Hardware based SAN Disk Replication. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Gordon, The proposed DR setup looks fine to me. During fail-over you have also described how the incoming request is routed to the DR setup.
As long as the routing is taken care, this DR setup looks good to me. I have seen customer setting up global load balancer, where the above routing is configured